# Javascript: find all "input" in a table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a shorter way to write this in JavaScript?

```
    var data = [];
    var table = document.getElementById( 'address' );
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName( 'tr' );
    for ( var x = 0; x < rows.length; x++ ) {
        var td = rows[x].getElementsByTagName( 'td' );
        for ( var y = 0; y < td.length; y++ ) {
            var input = td[y].getElementsByTagName( 'input' );
            for ( var z = 0; z < input.length; z++ ) {
                data.push( input[z].id );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added the script-tags only because I thought it might be necessary for highlighting.

Comment: When posting a question regarding DOM traversal, it's important to post the HTML markup you're using. That way, any confusion is eliminated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`element.getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1938918D) finds all descendants, not only children, so:

```
<script type="text/javascript> 

    var data = []; 
    var table = document.getElementById( 'address' ); 
    var input = table.getElementsByTagName( 'input' ); 
    for ( var z = 0; z < input.length; z++ ) { 
        data.push( input[z].id ); 
    } 

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep.

```
var data = [],
    inputs = document.getElementById('address').getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var z=0; z < inputs.length; z++)
  data.push(inputs[z].id);
```

Note, even in your longer version with three loops you can also say:

```
var rows = table.rows;
// instead of
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

// and, noting that it returns <th> cells as well as <td> cells,
// which in many cases doesn't matter:
var tds = rows[x].cells;
// instead of
var tds = rows[x].getElementsByTagName('td');
```

Answer (score 1):

For modern browsers `:)`

```
var table, inputs, arr;

table = document.getElementById( 'test' );
inputs = table.querySelectorAll( 'input' );
arr = [].slice.call( inputs ).map(function ( node ) { return node.id; });
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/HHaGg/

So instead of a `for` loop, I make use of the `map` method - each array element (each INPUT node) is replaced with its ID value.

Also note that `` `inputs.map(... `` doesn't work since `inputs` is a *NodeList* element - it's an array-like object, but not an standard array. To still use the `map` method on it, we just have to transform it into an array which is what `[].slice.call( inputs )` does for us.

Comment: Is this faster then the `for` loop?

Comment: Which is the last browser (the most modern browser) on which this doesn't work yet?

Comment: @sid IE8. `Array.prototype.map` is one of the new ES5 features.